# Create grid of different sized thumbnails?

Tags: ios, ipad, aqgridview

I'm trying to display a set of image thumbnails in a grid on the iPad.  I'm able to display a grid of images that are all 100x100 using AQGridView but I would like to include some images that are 200x200 (essentially, 4 spots in the grid).

For example, displaying 8 100x100 images and one 200x200 image like:

```
[1] [2] [3] [4]
[  5  ] [6] [7]
[     ] [8] [9]
```

Is there a way for AQGridView to do this?  Or other frameworks that have this type of functionality?

If not, perhaps someone can suggest a strategy that has been successful for them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AQGridView's sample on [reorganizing a springboard](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView/tree/master/Examples/SpringBoard) shows how to insert empty cell indexes to create the illusion of space.  Just insert 4 empty cells into the matrix and overlay a UIView, or implement some kind of flag that sets the cell's transform property to `CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.0, 2.0);` on a regular cell.